# How to have 2 separate PaperJS canvas items running side by side on same page?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I am using PaperJS on my webpage using vanilla JS.

One canvas works, but when I try another, only the last called canvas will render. No errors are thrown and as far as I'm aware, I'm scoping them correctly using `new PaperScope();`

**See an example here:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWgEXN?editors=0010

I have 2 functions (both identical) that should target 2 separate canvas elements on the page.

I'm trying to setup the scopes like so:

**Global object stored on the window:**

```
window.paper = {};
```

**Setup 1:**

```
function pattern_1(selector) {

  window.papers.paper_1 = new paper.PaperScope();

  const paperObj = window.papers.paper_1;
  const pattern = document.querySelector(selector);

  paperObj.install(window);

  window.onload = function () {
    paperObj.setup(pattern);
    // Etc etc, more code follows...
  }

}
```

**Setup 2 (identical, but different name):**

```
function pattern_2(selector) {

  window.papers.paper_2 = new paper.PaperScope();

  const paperObj = window.papers.paper_2;
  const pattern = document.querySelector(selector);

  paperObj.install(window);

  window.onload = function () {
    paperObj.setup(pattern);
    // Etc etc, more code follows...
  }

}
```

**They are then called like so:**

```
pattern_1('#item_1');
pattern_2('#item_2');
```

**The HTML looks like:**

```
<canvas id="item_1"></canvas>
<canvas id="item_2"></canvas>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong here?

Any help on scoping these out as separate items would be great. They do not need to communicate in any way with one another.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your `window.onload` method. A simplified version of what you have is:

```
function pattern_1(selector) {
  // code code code
  window.onload = function () {
    // Etc etc, more code follows...
  }
}

function pattern_2(selector) {
  // code code code
  window.onload = function () {
    // Etc etc, more code follows...
  }
}
pattern_1(...);
pattern_2(...);
```

When you call `pattern_1` you define the `onload` method for `window`. When you call `pattern_2`, you *overwrite* the `onload` method for `window`. This is why only your second canvas was receiving updates.

You can add more than one event listener by using `addEventListener`:

```
function pattern_1(selector) {
  // code code code
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // Etc etc, more code follows...
  });
}

function pattern_2(selector) {
  // code code code
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // Etc etc, more code follows...
  });
}
pattern_1(...);
pattern_2(...);
```

With this, each of your methods will add an event handler, so *both* of them will receive the event.

Comment: Oh. My. God. How dumb am I? Haha. That worked! It was something I totally overlooked as I was obsessed with the PaperScope() stuff. Thank you ever so much!